# Error FS0001: Expected to have type string, but has type char

Tags: f#

I am new to programming, and this is my first time working with a .NET language, so I apologise in advance if this question sounds really stupid/trivial.

Here are the relevant snippets of my code:

```
let isInteger (element: string) =
    let success, result = Int32.TryParse(element)
    if success then Some(result)
    else None
let removeUnnecessaryInfo (someString: string) =
    if isInteger someString.[-1] <> None then
        someString.Remove(-2, 2)
    else 
        someString.Remove(-1, 1)
```

However, when I try to run it in F# Interactive, I received the following message:

> "DuplicateFileFinder.fsx(15,22): error FS0001: This expression was expected to    have type
>      string
>   but here has type
>      char

I.e., "someString.[-1]" is classified as having the type char, which is why isInteger someString.[-1] fails.

Please give me some tips on the changes I can make to get the code to work. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way change the `if` to

```
 if isInteger (someString.[-1] |> string) <> None then
```

Comment: Thanks -- that works. If possible, can you kindly explain to me why someString.[-1] is considered to be char rather than string?

Comment: A string is an array of `char` - each element is a `char`

Comment: In terms of base types, a string is more like a sequence of `char` which happens to have an `Item` property. In F#, a slice of a string is still a string: `"abc".[1..1]` gets you `"b"`.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what character do you actually get for `someString.[-1]`?  I get an `IndexOutOfRangeException`.